# how to delete a dynamic added pushbutton?

Tags: qt

I added a dynamic pushbutton by using

```
 QPushButton *p=new QPushButton("button");
```

I want to click a button "add" to add a button, and click "delete" to delete this button.

I realize this by using a gridlayout, but I find it is not good because the overall view shrinks as I add the button. How to dynamically add and remove buttons without gridlayout? Or how to set gridlayout so that when adding and removing buttons, it will not automatically scale?

what I mean is:

add one button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znL3R.png)

add three buttons:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwzYG.png)

add many buttons:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS68U.png)

As shown in the images, the more buttons there are, the smaller each button becomes.What I want to do is the buttons that dynamically added to the gridlayout don't look smaller and smaller as the number of buttons increases (I know their size don't change, they just look smaller and smaller)

besides, could you please tell me how to use

```
     QMouseEvent::globalX(QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
```

there is an error that:

Semantic Issue

32:31: error: call to non-static member function without an object argument

thanks!

Comment: The whole question is a bit unclear. Please, provide a [mcve] to make your intention clear. _I find it is not good because the overall view shrinks as I add the button._ I tried to imagine how this could be made with the effect you described but I failed. Concerning `QMouseEvent::globalX(QEvent::MouseButtonPress)`: Yeah, that doesn't work. What was your actual intention?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't express my meaning clearly. I have added three pictures, which should be able to express my meaning clearly

Comment: @Marcus,did you get any solution for this ?.I too need a solution to delete dynamically added buttons.